# 2 Java Strings in different encoding?

Tags: java, string, file-io, encoding, utf-8

I have a problem. I thought Java-Strings are always encoded as UTF-16? Now I have a file with the text "TEST", which is encoded in UTF-8 with BOM. When I read from the file with `Files.newBufferedReader(test_file)` it gives me a String with UTF-8 with BOM encoding.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader( test_file )){
    reader.lines().forEach( 
        s -> {
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString( s.getBytes() ) );
            System.out.println( Arrays.toString( "TEST".getBytes()) );
            System.out.println( s.equals("TEST") );
        } );
} catch( Exception e ) {}
```

I don't specify any encoding here. But the strange thing is, the output looks like this:

```
[-17, -69, -65, 84, 69, 83, 84]
[84, 69, 83, 84]
false
```

How is this possible? It looks like I have two String with different encoding in Java...

The problem is, I need "s" as a key for a `HashMap<String, String>`. But the key is "TEST" and `s.equals("TEST")` returns false and therefore the HashMap returns null, when I try `mymap.get(s)`.

Comment: `s.getBytes()` uses the unspecified platform default encoding, which can be UTF-8, ASCII, or _whatever._  It's really 100% never a good idea to call `String.getBytes()` without an argument.  But really, print out `s`.  (Could `s` have invisible characters?  It looks like frankly it might.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the BufferedReader is reading your BOM. The sequence `-17, -69, -65` is simply the BOM of UTF-8. But the literal `"Test"` does not contain the BOM and so the strings aren't equal.

Comment: But both, s and "TEST" are Java-Strings. How is it possible to have 2 Java Strings with different encoding?

Comment: You have to **skip the BOM** manually, because BufferedReader is reading what the file contains and the file contains the BOM. Both Java Strings have the **same encoding**. But only one is containg the BOM.

Comment: Omg, I got it. Sorry for that.